# How get "In house iOS app" downloading/install count?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-house-distribution

I have uploaded **In house iOS app** on **Web server** using Enterprise certificate. How can get application downloading count without launching application ? So that we can show downloading count on **Web-Server** for application analysis purpose.

Comment: Add analytics on the portal where you have host the application.

Comment: and maybe also analytics in the app (so you can count how often it is being launched etc)

Comment: Thank you @Apurv and Thilo... I have no idea of 'analytics'. Please explain or give few links so that I understand how it work.
Can we get count without open app(launching app) with the help of analytics.

Comment: @Deepak, no one knows anything about your hosting server, how can you expect that someone else to do such job for you?

Comment: please share more info on your web server. so that it would be easy to give info about your question